# How can I test multiple variables and act on them individually in a C# if statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have some basic code in my C# program, which uses 3 if statements.

```
if (leftIndex >= imageList.Count - 1)
{
    leftIndex = 0;
}
if (middleIndex >= imageList.Count - 1)
{
    middleIndex = 0;
}
if (rightIndex >= imageList.Count - 1)
{
    rightIndex = 0;
}
```

This works fine for the code itself, but I was wondering how I'd simplify it to act on each individually, in case I had more variables to work with.

Comment: _"how I'd simplify it to act on each individually"_ - but that's what your code already does...

Comment: Sorry, I meant simplify it to act on each individually with one if statement instead of using multiple.

Comment: Are you shure the logic is okay? Indices go from 0 to Count - 1. I.e., when the index is greater or equal to Count you have to wrap around. Count - 1 itself is still in the range. Another way to wrap around after incrementing an index is to write: `index = (index + 1) % imageList.Count` (% = modulo operator). No if, no ternary operator.

Comment: @forefie: Are you just looking to put that logic into a method that you can re-invoke instead of copying/pasting the logic?  What have you tried?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes It looks a little odd, but there is a second image that calls from imageList[middleIndex + 1], so this is my way around it, which works for what I'm trying.

Comment: If you are using middleIndex + 1 as an index then `Count - 1`  is okay. But you could also write `imageList[(middleIndex + 1) % imageList.Count]`. It may look odd to you , but this a very common math trick. See also: [How to Wrap Around a Range of Numbers with the Modulo](https://dev.to/jvon1904/how-to-wrap-around-a-range-of-numbers-with-the-modulo-cdo).

Comment: That many index variables may suggest larger design issues. Why not encapsulate each index with its corresponding list in a simple type? `record Indexed(List<Image> images) { private int index = 0; public int Index { get => index; set => index = value >= images.Count - 1 ? 0 : value; } }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a method with a ref parameter:

```
private void ModifyIndex(ref int index)
{
  if (index >= imageList.Count - 1)
  {
      index = 0;
  }
}
```

Usage is

```
ModifyIndex(ref leftIndex);
ModifyIndex(ref middleIndex);
ModifyIndex(ref rightIndex);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) returning the result of a [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator):

```
int getIndex(int baseIndex) =>
    (baseIndex >= imageList.Count - 1) ? 0 : baseIndex;

leftIndex = getIndex(leftIndex);
middleIndex = getIndex(middleIndex);
rightIndex = getIndex(rightIndex);
```